# My lo interface is down on boot. What can I do?

Tags: networking, centos6, loopback

My `lo` interface is down when the system boot. I can turn it up with `ifconfig up lo` but I wonder what could be the cause? Where can I look to debug such problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Make sure the network service is configured to start at boot.

   ```
   # chkconfig --list network
   network         0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
   ```

   Runlevels 0, 1 and 6 should show as `off` (as they result in shutting down or restarting the system, or bringing it to single user mode) and the rest should be `on`.

   If it isn't enabled, then you should enable it.

   ```
   # chkconfig network on
   ```
2. Make sure the `lo` interface is configured correctly.

   Check `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-lo` and make sure it hasn't been altered. On my CentOS 6.5 system it appears as:

   ```
   DEVICE=lo
   IPADDR=127.0.0.1
   NETMASK=255.0.0.0
   NETWORK=127.0.0.0
   # If you're having problems with gated making 127.0.0.0/8 a martian,
   # you can change this to something else (255.255.255.255, for example)
   BROADCAST=127.255.255.255
   ONBOOT=yes
   NAME=loopback
   ```

Comment: For some reason the /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-lo is not found on my VPS. I added this (as you did) and the loopback interface started on boot now. Thanks a lot man.